# Powershell script to get all app services linked with there certificates

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell

Can somebody tell me how can I build a script that can list out all the app service certificates inside of an app services and app service plan that the app services are linked with inside of any azure subscription?

Comment: If my reply is helpful, you could mark or vote it to help others to find, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official documentation, **Azure PowerShell** does **not** support get **certificate** and **service plan** via the **App Service Name** . If you want to do it, you could get them via **resource group**.

1.Get Web App certificates in a resource group

```
Get-AzureRmWebAppCertificate -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroup>
```

2.Get App Service plans from a resource group

```
Get-AzureRmAppServicePlan -ResourceGroupName <resourcegroup>
```

For more details, refer to [Get-AzureRmWebAppCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/Get-AzureRmWebAppCertificate?view=azurermps-6.0.0) & [Get-AzureRmAppServicePlan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.websites/Get-AzureRmAppServicePlan?view=azurermps-6.0.0).